# Determine the set of all the isomorphism classes of differentiable $M$-bundles over $X$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory, diffeomorphism

Let $M$ be an instantaneously analytic, closed, $C^\infty,$ $2-$manifold, with genus, $g=0,$ endowed with a metric that restricts contractibility. Contractibility is restricted to avoid the deformation of $M$ into $S^2.$

An important problem is to

> Determine the set of all the isomorphism classes of differentiable $M$-bundles
>
> $$ \pi:E\to X $$
>
> over $X:=\Bbb T^3.$

What I know is that this problem can be translated into a problem in homotopy theory. Let Diff$(M)$ be the diffeomorphism group of $M$ equipped with the $C^\infty$ topology and let $B$ Diff $(M)$ be its classifying space. Then we have a natural identification

$\{$isomorphism classses of smooth M-bundles over X$\} \cong \ [X,B$ Diff $(M)$$].$

where the RHS denotes the set of all the homotopy classes of continuous mappings from $X$ to $B$ Diff $(M).$ So in essence I have to figure out how to compute the homotopy groups $\pi_i($Diff $(M)).$

Comment: There are several things about this post which are unclear. First, what is your question? Second, what is "instantaneously analytic"? Third, every closed $C^\infty$ 2-manifold of genus $g=0$ is $C^\infty$-diffeomorphic to $S^2$, and hence is not contractible, so I have no idea what extra restriction you are attempting to impose by saying that $M$ is "endowed with a metric that restricts contractibility".

Comment: @LeeMosher I am in the process of making edits. Thanks for your feedback